# Footer overlaps content at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, footer, html

I have got my footer to stay at the bottom of the page however it is overlapping the content and i cant stop it.

I have looked all over the internet for a solution and none works. I have a feeling that i need to move divs around etc but i could be wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Concert+One" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Eczar" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css">
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
       <img src="img/top-bar/bar.png" height="10px" class="top">
        <ul id="menu-bar">
            <li><a href="#header" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#first" class="smoothScroll">Page 1</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Page 2</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Drop 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Drop 2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="img/archery-1839284.jpg" class="cover">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
           <div id="first" class="item">
                <p class="para">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime distinctio sed officia, nam iure quam necessitatibus nobis non, aut quaerat autem. Quam mollitia, fugiat amet veritatis, voluptate earum quidem et! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci ex earum impedit ipsum consequatur dolor doloremque eum. Sed fugit dolor maiores pariatur nesciunt iste cupiditate consequuntur, dolore alias numquam voluptatum!
                </p>
           </div>
           <div id="img-span">
               <img src="img/board-911636.jpg" class="wide">
           </div>
           <div class="item" style="background-color: red;">
               <p class="para">
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem sit non ipsam aut perferendis neque magnam deleniti, officia necessitatibus porro odio ipsum est eum aliquam nulla placeat, deserunt? Atque, nisi.
               </p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <img src="img/top-bar/bar.png" height="10px" class="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Eczar', serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.top {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3000;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.bottom {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100%;
}

.cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/archery-1839284.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.item {
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.item p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.img-span {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative
}

.wide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    z-index: 3000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the #footer to position: relative; will fix the overlapping issue.

```
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background-color: greenyellow;
position: relative;
clear: both; }
```

But you should have a look at the following website which explains how to create a footer that will always stick on the bottom of the page, with large or with small contents. This would be a much better way.

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Thanks alot i can't believe i didnt try that haha :D

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the way you go at it is the best but what would work in your case is to change your wrapper class adding a padding bottom equal to your footer height like:

```
#wrapper {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100%;
}
#footer {
    height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your problem you want stick your footer to the bottom of your page right ? so, that you have to put following css code to

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

body {
margin-bottom:70px;
}
```